# Selecting files in a CircleCI environment results in "uninitialized constant Diff" error

Tags: rspec, continuous-integration, glob, circleci

Locally I am running these things:

```
ruby: 2.5
bundler: 2.0.1
rspec: 3.8
```

I am trying to use CircleCI to run tests for a number of files but none of the documented ways appears to be working.

```
TESTFILES=$(circleci tests glob "spec/**/*.rb" | circleci tests split --split-by=timings)
bundle exec rspec -- ${TESTFILES}
```

gives:

```
An error occurred while loading ./vendor/bundle/gems/diff-lcs-1.3/spec/change_spec.rb.
Failure/Error:
  describe Diff::LCS::Change do
    describe "an add" do
      subject { described_class.new('+', 0, 'element') }
      it { should_not be_deleting   }
      it { should     be_adding     }
      it { should_not be_unchanged  }
      it { should_not be_changed    }
      it { should_not be_finished_a }
      it { should_not be_finished_b }
    end

NameError:
  uninitialized constant Diff
# ./vendor/bundle/gems/diff-lcs-1.3/spec/change_spec.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
```

---

so then I tried:

```
TESTFILES=$(circleci tests glob "**/*spec*.rb") # | circleci tests split --split-by=timings)
bundle exec rspec -- ${TESTFILES}
```

but that gives same error.

So I changed to

```
TESTFILES=$(circleci tests glob "**/*spec*.rb") # | circleci tests split --split-by=timings)
bundle exec rspec -- ${TESTFILES}
```

But that gives

```
/bin/bash: line 1: glob: command not found
```

So then I tried just using find

```
TESTFILES=$(find . -name "*_spec.rb")
```

but that goes back to the same original message:

```
An error occurred while loading ./vendor/bundle/gems/diff-lcs-1.3/spec/lcs_spec.rb.
Failure/Error:
  describe Diff::LCS::Internals, ".lcs" do
    include Diff::LCS::SpecHelper::Matchers
```

The only thing that seems to work is to NOT try and prep the list of filenames and simply just have

```
bundle exec rspec
```

in my

```
.circleci/config file in a `run:` `command:` section
```

That works.  Although it doesn't actually select `*_spec.rb` files in the *top level* directory, only in the `rspec/` directory - which is a bit odd given that the find command files both current and subdirectories  but using it here only finds 1 file.

I then managed to get around that issue that by using

```
bundle exec rspec .  # Note the dot at the end
```

Although I can run ALL tests now, the question  remains - how could I select a list of files?  All the methods seems to be broken in a few ways when I am trying CircleCI currently.